# delete object in template - django

Tags: django

My main page has many sub pages and on each of the sub pages i have many items listed. Next to item i want a delete button and when you press it the item must be deleted but you must remain on the same page. Is there a way that when i press the delete button i send the id of the object to view but still remain on the same page ?

In view of each subpages i would have code like this:

```
if request.method == 'GET'  and 'delete' in request.GET:
```

Now i need a way to get id of object that is next to delete button so i can delete it. I saw some solutions online using urls but the problem is i would have to write a special url for each of the 7 subpages.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to call an API delete function ( see Django rest Framework )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i found a simple solution, but i would like you to comment. So in template when i click a delete button, i send both name of subpage and id of object through the url:

```
<a href="delete/graficna/{{ graficna.id}}" >    
                <button> delete</button>
            </a>
```

I use this url:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<vrsta>\w+)/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

In views i simply use if statements to find out from which subpage i am calling the delete function and then use the id to find the object and delete it. After that i return to the page from which i called the delete.

```
def delete(request, vrsta, id):     

if vrsta == 'graficna':
    graficna = Graficna.objects.get(pk=id).delete() 
    return redirect('graficne')

if vrsta == 'procesor':
    procesor = Procesor.objects.get(pk=id).delete() 
    return redirect('procesor')

return redirect('main')
```

So what do you think about this approach ?

Comment: I think i did really well and deserve some recognition :D